# How to map 'localhost' to minikube with Ingress

Tags: localhost, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I'm using minikube version 1.4.0 and Kubernetes version 1.16.0 on MacOS 10.15.

I'm developing some authorization/authentication code that relies on an external service. In the API calls to the service, I'm required to provide a redirect URL. The URL has to be either 1) a legit FQDN from an external service (when I go to production) or 2) `localhost/<whatever>`. My code, however, does not use `localhost` - it uses a custom `minikube.local` which maps to Minikube's IP (as opposed to 127.0.0.1).

Note - I could use `NodePort` type Kubernetes services and `port-forward` them which would, for example, allow me to hit my Django server at `localhost:8000`. However, I am choosing to use Ingress (so my Minikube environment most closely resembles my production environment) which takes away this ability.

Is there a way to use localhost instead of my Minikube's IP and its associated DNS name?

Comment: Hello s g,
I don't really know if this is possible but you can use this documentation[1] to access your host resources and there is also a GitHub K8s discussion about it[2]. 

Hope this helps you!

[1] https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/accessing-host-resources/
[2] https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2735

Comment: It's possible and this is your guide to creating ingress using NGINX in Minikube https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/ this guide relies on address resolution using `/etc/hosts` file

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test your backend is working you can do something like this:

```
curl -H 'Host: localhost' -v $(minikube ip)
```

For it to work in the browser you need an ssh tunnel, this one works for me:

```
ssh -i $(minikube ssh-key) docker@$(minikube ip) -L 8008:localhost:80
```

This maps port 80 in minikube's cluster to 8008 in localhost. If you want to map port 80 then you will need add sudo, at least for some linux distros.